# Random number generation in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following function,

```
foo <- function(x) {
    print(x)
    print(x)
}
```

And suppose I do this,

```
foo(runif(1))
```

I get the following result,

```
[1] 0.5354641
[1] 0.5354641
```

Or some other random number. What I want is for there to be two different numbers as the output. Is this possible? In other words I would like,

```
[1] 0.5354641
[1] 0.2895715
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being down voted. This is a question about lazy evaluation... and...

Comment: Probably because this question is about how to use R, not about statistics, & is off topic here. If you wait, we will migrate this to [SO] for you.

Comment: You can migrate this one and the similar one I posted. If it takes long, I'll just repost there.

Comment: you're probably looking for `print(eval(substitute(x)))` -- but that's probably a bad idea.  I second the request for more context.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to decipher what you want from the comments, I think you want to be able to pass a random number generating function to another function and have it run several times.  For some reason you can't just specify it inside the main `foo` function (this is where context would have helped).  I think you want something that uses `match.fun()` like this:

```
foo <- function(FUN) {
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    print(FUN())
    print(FUN())
}

my_runif <- function(){
    runif(1)
}

foo(my_runif)
```

It does what you want I think:

```
> foo(my_runif)
[1] 0.6657059
[1] 0.7969368
```

Comment: @IQ472 does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

`replicate(2, runif(1))` Answers must be at least 30 characters.

Comment: This answers this question. But it's not what I want. I need something for an unknown number of calls in the function.

Comment: @IQ472 It's unclear whether you want to change 1 or 2, but in either case, you can just pass it the number of calls you wish to perform due to lazy evaluation.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do and why `runif(2)` doesn't work. Maybe you need to add some more context to the question?